# Compile C# code on server

Tags: c#, compilation, server, vwdexpress

I am using a remote windows VM to edit/develop a survey system. Using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express as my IDE. I want to compile this project but the option is disabled. I’m not even sure if it has to be compiled, though.

**(A)** Is it possible this is being compiled on runtime?

**(B)** Is there a way to check if this is working correctly?

---

This is the master folder:

[image: Master Folder of App]

And this is the App_Code folder:

[image: App's App_Code Folder]

When I have the any file open, the `Debug > Start Debugging (F5)` option is disabled and there are no other “Compile” options. I've tried compiling everything as a folder and don't think that worked either.

Thank you in advance.

*~ EDIT ~*

The Solutions Explorer Window looks like this:

[image: Solutions Explorer Window]

**RESOLVED**

The server automatically compiles the code on run.

Thank you [@Ňuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286670/%C5%87uf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspicious that you are missing project file. If this is the case, go to File->New Project->ASP.NET Web Application->OK and then in Solution Explorer right-click on project->Add->Existing Item and select all files that you created earlier, to add them to the project. After that, menu item Debug->Start debugging should be available.

Comment: Also, the template web project added a lot of extra files. Are those needed?

Comment: Can you confirm that in your Solution Exprorer, you have Solution as a root node and Project as it's child? And if you right-click project, you have "Build Web Site" enabled on top of the context menu?

Comment: I have included this in the description above

Comment: Please can you also right-click project and select "Set as StartUp project" - afterwards project shoud be displayed in bold font. If no startup project is set, Visual Studio obviously cannot debug it.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing that option

Comment: Which option you don't see - Build Web Site, or Set as StartUp project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84399/discussion-between-uf-and-iskore).